# Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126

Tags: angular, vercel

I am developing an angular app. I can run the project without any problem with ng serve. When I tried to publish the project with Vercel I got errors:

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you try the command with `--unsafe-perm`? Let me know if that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: No, I didn't  trying this command